# How to disable by overriding webkit-transform and not deleting the line

Tags: css

I have a css file that I don't want to alter (for my own reasons) so what I did is create a new css file and I override what every css line that needed changing. Now how can I cancel out this line of code:

```
@media (max-width: 480px)
    .nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I want to disable the -webkit-transform, it is making some issues.
Another thing I would like to know what is this exactly doing? Maybe I can solve this issue in an another way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just set `-webkit-transform: none`. You can read more about it here: [MDN transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)